# UInt64 and "The operation overflows at compile time in checked mode" - CS0220

Tags: c#, math, logic, uint64

This feels like a stupid question, but I can't seem to see the answer. I have an UInt64, which is supposed to have a max value of

```
UInt64.MaxValue 18446744073709551615
```

However, when I try to assign a modest-sized number, I get this overflow error of "The operation overflows at compile time in checked mode". If I wrap it in an "unchecked" block then it compiles, and runs as if this variable is zero:

```
UInt64 value1 = 1073741824 * 8; // Compile error CS0220
UInt64 value2 = 8589934592;     // Actual value - no error
```

Why is this happenning?

Comment: Ahh yes - that would absolutely explain it! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Because:

```
UInt64 value1 = 1073741824 * 8;
```

Is doing the arithmetic as a signed 32-bit integer, *then* converting it to an `ulong`. Try:

```
UInt64 value1 = 1073741824UL * 8;
```

The `UL` means that the literal is of an unsigned long. See section 2.4.4 of the C# Specification for more on literal suffixes:

> If the literal is suffixed by UL, Ul, uL, ul, LU, Lu, lU, or lu, it is of type ulong

Answer (score 4):

`1073741824` is an `int`, not a `UInt64`.
Therefore, your multiplication overflows the limit of a 32-bit signed integer.

Add the `ul` (unsigned long) suffix to either operand.

Answer (score 1):

You've got an error because you operate with `int` instead of `long`
1073741824 is still `int` (max for `int` is 2147483647).
So in first case you get overflow of `int` type.
Change first expression with:

```
UInt64 value1 = 1073741824L * 8;
```

and problem will disappear.

Comment: didn't notice you operate with unsigned value. For unsigned long you should use 1073741824UL instead of 1073741824L.