# 'The operation overflows at compile time in checked mode' Error

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, numbers

When I try to create the following variable:

```
UInt64 mod32 = (UInt64)(UInt32.MaxValue + 1);
```

and I get the following Error: '`The operation overflows at compile time in checked mode`'

How can I fix/ignore this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UInt64 and "The operation overflows at compile time in checked mode"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167219/uint64-and-the-operation-overflows-at-compile-time-in-checked-mode)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do as below:

```
UInt64 mod32 = UInt32.MaxValue + (UInt64)1;
```

When you do `(UInt64)(UInt32.MaxValue + 1)` the program will try to do `UInt32.MaxValue + 1` first, which is the reason for the error, and then cast to `UInt64`.